# iOS7 Testing Background fetch in Simulator?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ios7, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I know there are ways to do it with XCode 5 but is it possible with my infrastructure?
I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and MonoTouch.

In XCode I can go under Debug > "Simulate Background Fetch" or there is also a second way: XCode Menu, "Product" => "Scheme" => "Edit Scheme" enable the option "Background Fetch".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this is currently not possible in Xamarin Studio/Visual Studio.

But [we're working on it](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=14670), and it will be included in a future release.

Comment: @Yiding: AFAIK this has been implemented, but hasn't reached any released version of Xamarin Studio / Xamarin.iOS yet.

Comment: Good to know. So test on the real device with customized fetch time is the only choice for now I guess?

Comment: Any plans on releasing this feature?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed the new update of Xamarin Studio 5.0 included Background Fetch support. (http://docs.xamarin.com/releases/studio/xamarin.studio_5.0/xamarin.studio_5.0/)

When debugging using the simulator, go to **Run->Simulate IOS Background Fetch**

Comment: I can see this option in Xamarin Studio, but not in Visual Studio with the Xamarin plugin.

Comment: I'm debugging in Xamarin studio with the simulator, but I'm not seeing this option.

Answer (score 0):

This can now be done in Xamarin Studio only and only using the iOS Simulators. Make sure your iOS project already has the Background Fetch permission selected (in your iOS project properties or manually in your `info.plist`). Then, in Xamarin Studio, you choose **Run** -> **Run With** -> **Custom Configuration** -> Select **Background Fetch** -> **Run**

That will launch your app in the background and will force a background fetch to happen.

Once you do that, you should not have a separate option listed under your configuration dropdown for iOS. There should not be a **.iOS** and an **ProjectName.iOS - Background Fetch** option in the dropdown. The nice thing about this is that, after selecting **ProjectName.iOS - Background Fetch** and running the app, while the app is still running, you can go to **Run** -> **Simulate iOS Background Fetch** to run the fetch multiple times. This option is always greyed out for me if I run my app using the Custom Configuration window though.